# Implementing a diplomatic AXI Stream interface in Chisel - BundleMap.cloneType error

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to build a minimal example, of how to generate an AXI4Stream interface using Chisel and diplomacy. I am using the diplomatic interface already available in rocket-chip (freechips.rocketchip.amba.axis). I have some experience with Chisel, but I am still trying to learn diplomacy.

Anyway, I've managed to create a small APB example using the answer provided here: [IP block generation/testing when using diplomacy. Possible to give dummy node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63909300/ip-block-generation-testing-when-using-diplomacy-possible-to-give-dummy-node?rq=1)

Following that, I tried to create a similar, simple AXI Stream example, but I keep getting errors. Concretely, I get the following error:

> [error] (Compile / run) java.lang.Exception: Unable to use BundleMap.cloneType on class freechips.rocketchip.amba.axis.AXISBundleBits, probably because class freechips.rocketchip.amba.axis.AXISBundleBits does not have a constructor accepting BundleFields.  Consider overriding cloneType() on class freechips.rocketchip.amba.axis.AXISBundleBits

The code:

```
package chipyard.example
import chisel3._
import chisel3.internal.sourceinfo.SourceInfo
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage
import freechips.rocketchip.config.{Config, Parameters}
import freechips.rocketchip.amba.axis._
import freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy.{SimpleNodeImp, ValName, SourceNode, NexusNode, 
                                       SinkNode, LazyModule, LazyModuleImp, TransferSizes,
                                       SimpleDevice, AddressSet}

class MyAxisController(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {
  val device = new SimpleDevice("my-device", Seq("tutorial,my-device0"))
  val axisParams = AXISSlaveParameters.v1(name = "axisSlave", supportsSizes = TransferSizes(8,8))
  val axisPortParams = AXISSlavePortParameters.v1(slaves = Seq(axisParams))
  val node = AXISSlaveNode(portParams = Seq(axisPortParams))

  lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
      val ins = node.in.unzip._1
      val register = RegInit(UInt(8.W), 0.U)
      register := register + ins(0).bits.data
  }
}

class AXISMaster()(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {
  val axisMasterParams = AXISMasterParameters.v1(
    name = "axisMaster", emitsSizes = TransferSizes(8, 8)
  )

  val axisMasterPortParams = AXISMasterPortParameters.v1(
    masters = Seq(axisMasterParams),
    beatBytes = Option(8)
  )

  val node = AXISMasterNode(
    portParams = Seq(axisMasterPortParams)
  )

  
  lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
    //The dontTouch here preserves the interface so logic is generated
    dontTouch(node.out.head._1)
  }
}


class MyAxisWrapper()(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {
  val master = LazyModule(new AXISMaster)
  val slave  = LazyModule(new MyAxisController()(Parameters.empty))

  slave.node := master.node 

  lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
    //nothing???
  }
}
```

and Main.scala:

````
package chipyard.example

import chisel3._
import freechips.rocketchip.config.Parameters
import freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy._

import java.io.File
import java.io.FileWriter


/**
 * An object extending App to generate the Verilog code.
 */
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //(new chisel3.stage.ChiselStage).execute(args, Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => LazyModule(new MyWrapper()(Parameters.empty)).module)))

    val verilog = (new chisel3.stage.ChiselStage).emitVerilog(
                   LazyModule(new MyAxisWrapper()(Parameters.empty)).module
    )
    //println(s"```verilog\n$verilog```")

    val fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("./gen/gen.v"))
    fileWriter.write(verilog)
    fileWriter.close()

  }
}
````

The code is also available at https://github.com/jurevreca12/temp_dspblock_example/tree/axistream2/scala/main.

My question is. Why do I get this error? Or am I doing something wrong in the first place, and is there an easier way to create an AXIStream module?

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be an issue with Rocket-Chip's changes to bump to Chisel 3.5. During those changes, `AXISBundleBits` had its cloneType removed even though it extends off BundleMap (and therefore requires cloneType due to extending off `Record`).

I don't have all the details of cloneType at this time, but essentially:

- Records require cloneType
- Bundles used to require cloneType, but since the compiler plugin was implemented, as of 3.5 they no longer require cloneType.
- `BundleMap` is a confusing case because it is a custom Bundle type extending directly off Record and isn't of type Bundle. There's a comment saying it explicitly requires a field constructor in an extended class.

```scala
// If you extend this class, you must either redefine cloneType or have a fields constructor
class BundleMap(val fields: Seq[BundleFieldBase]) extends Record with CustomBulkAssignable {
  // All fields must have distinct key.names
  require(fields.map(_.key.name).distinct.size == fields.size)

  val elements: ListMap[String, Data] = ListMap(fields.map { bf => bf.key.name -> chisel3.experimental.DataMirror.internal.chiselTypeClone(bf.data) } :_*)


  override def cloneType: this.type = {
    try {
      this.getClass.getConstructors.head.newInstance(fields).asInstanceOf[this.type]
    } catch {
      case e: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException =>
        throw new Exception("Unable to use BundleMap.cloneType on " +
                       this.getClass + ", probably because " + this.getClass +
                       " does not have a constructor accepting BundleFields.  Consider overriding " +
                       "cloneType() on " + this.getClass, e)
    }
  }
```

Therefore, it shouldn't have had its cloneType method removed during the 3.5 Chisel bump and that will need to be added back for AXIS in RC's main branch to start working again.

```
class AXISBundleBits(val params: AXISBundleParameters) extends BundleMap(AXISBundle.keys(params)) {
 override def cloneType: this.type = (new AXISBundleBits(params)).asInstanceOf[this.type] // This line was removed!
  def last = if (params.hasLast) apply(AXISLast) else true.B
  def id   = if (params.hasId)   apply(AXISId)   else 0.U
  def dest = if (params.hasDest) apply(AXISDest) else 0.U
```

Edit: the cloneType exception issue is now fixed for 3.5 on the main branch :)